# How to stay on a loop while scraping a site with linked lists in python

Tags: python

I am scraping a site where by there are links, these links have got children and their children spawn their own children. And the children also spawn their own children. I would want my code to stay on a loop. Scrape and then find the links in a, then store them on a list, follow up on the children, scrape the detailed information and then continue to the end. Then start on b and follow on the generations of children with their children. Then proceed to c doing the same thing. My question is how do I do something like that in python, whilst staying in a loop. If there is someone who has come accross a problem like this please may you help suggest how would you go about it ad what would be the best strategy. Below is a tree to draw a picture on these relations.

parents = [a, b, c]

```
a_children = [e, f, g]

    e_children =  [h, j, k]

        f_children = [l, m, n]

            g_children = [o, p, q]
                h_children = [r, s, t]
```

I would like to have this function to run on a loop to the end

```
def scrape_save_and_continue(driver, nodes):
    print('Scraping Saving & Continuing..')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Continuing ...')
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Shouldn't this problem better suited to dictionaries ?
Edit: if you want to just print them, check out breadth-first-search (the loop/non-recursive version).

Answer (score 0):

In python this is all about indentation.
If you take a for loop it will complete everything in this indentation before continuing to the next element in the list/range.

```
example_list = [a, b, c]
for letter in example_list:
    for _ in range(0, 2):
        print(letter)
```

because of indentation this will print:

a

a

b

b

c

c

Comment: Yes it helps I wasnt confident on the for loop as I dont know when the children stop having children. But I think I can work with a for loop and come up with something. Thank you a lot. i shall post my solution when done